# Showing or hiding an item in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

Im basically need to be able to show or hide an item in a list

such that when i choose an option an item is shown if it's hidden such as below

```
a = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']

def askChoice():
    choice = 0
    if choice == 1:
        a[-1] = X ##Therefore last item in the list is hidden

    elif choice == 2:
        a[-1] = a[-1] ##Therefore item shown

    else:
        a[-1] = [] ## There an empty placeholder where any other item can be placed

    return choice
```

Comment: Er, what? Perhaps you could elaborate on the context of this, because you seem to be trying to do something with a list that makes no sense. `a[-1] = a[-1]`? That does nothing.

Comment: Setting `choice` to 0 will ensure the last condition, the `else`, is executed every time.

Comment: @Amber, a[-1] in choice 2 should make a last item shown if it has been hidden using a X. By the way im not familier with python as yet so i need your help please. thanks

Comment: The above doesnt show exactly what i want to do, but i basically need to show or hide any item in a list

Comment: I'd recommend messing around with a Python tutorial or something for a bit, just to get a basic grasp of the language.

Comment: "show" and "hide" don't make any sense here. The list contains stuff. Showing or hiding is completely unrelated; that has to do with what you choose to output to the screen, not what your data is. You can, for example, produce *a list that consists of the things that should be shown*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the information about which items in the list are shown or hidden.

I would do something like:

```
a = [['A',True], ['B',True], ['C',True], ['D',True], ['E',True]]

def show(index):
    a[index][1] = True

def hide(index):
    a[index][1] = False

def display():
    print([x[0] for x in a if x[1]])
```

There are other methods, but storing the info in your list means you won't run into confusing bugs where your data on what to show and what not to does not match up with your actual printable data. It also ensures you will have to update show/hide data when you update the list, which otherwise could be easily overlooked.